# modeling binary outcomes with multiple binary categorical variables

Tags: r, regression, logistic, statistical-significance, modeling

I have an ad awareness test design, but I'm needing some help on how valid the test is and how I can go about analyzing.

I want to run a digital ad campaign and survey a panel with 3 different test groups.

--

In the survey, there will be two questions regarding awareness of advertising

-First ask “Have you seen brand advertising in the past 7 days?”

-If yes, then “Where have you seen brand advertising in the past 7 days” with answer choices for different channels (internet connected devices, broadcast TV, billboards, etc)

--

2 control groups and 1 exposed group

-First control group = those that were not exposed to digital media and stated they have not seen brand advertising in the past 7 days

-Second control group = those that were not exposed and have said they’ve seen brand advertising in the past 7 days

-Exposed group = those that were marked as being digitally exposed to brand advertising

--

**This is where the question begins...**

Does it make sense to use logistic regression to understand how self-stated exposure to advertisement (q2) through different channels contribute to awareness of advertising (q1)?

How do you imagine the analysis would be done in R?

What would make the most sense in terms of using the digitally exposed piece for analysis?